# Edit DataTemplate Bindings in Code Behind UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to create a generic ListView page where I can show all the items on a `List<object>` where I don't know which fields will be shown.

I intend that the page when on navigated receives the `List<object>` and the fields I want to show in a `Dictionary<string, string>` where the first string represents if the field is a header, subheader, or image and in the second the name of the property that I want to bind to the header/subheader/image as parameters.

At the moment my C# code looks like this:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var param = (Dictionary<string, object>)e.Parameter;
    _ItemsList = (List<object>)param["itemsList"];
    var fields = (Dictionary<string, string>)param["fields"];

    _DetailsPage = (Type)param["detailPage"];
    ObjListView.ItemsSource = UniversalAutoSuggestBox.ItemsSource = _ItemsList;
}
```

My problem is that the data bindings are defined on a DataTemplate on my view XAML:

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="NormalItemTemplate">
            <Grid MinWidth="350"
                      Margin="5">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Ellipse Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                 Width ="32"
                                 Height="32"
                                 Margin="6"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Ellipse.Fill>
                        <ImageBrush x:Name="LogoImage" ImageSource="{Binding Image}"/>
                    </Ellipse.Fill>
                </Ellipse>

                <TextBlock x:Name="HeaderTextBlock"
                                   Grid.Row="0" 
                                   Grid.Column="1"
                                   Text="{Binding Header}"
                                   Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"
                                   Margin="12,6,0,0"/>

                <TextBlock x:Name="FooterTextBlock" 
                           Grid.Row="1"
                                   Grid.Column="1"
                                   Text="{Binding Subheader}"
                                   Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"
                                   Margin="12,0,0,6"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

I want to know if there is a way I can dynamically change the data bindings to the property that I get from the fields dictionary and what is the best solution to do so or if it's better to use a different approach there.

Comment: The most easy way to display a list of whatever is likely to bind that list to a DataGrid and let the grid auto generate the columns. Of course this won't look nice.
If you want to control your bindings in code, have a look at BindigOperations and Binding class itself. At least that's 1 way to go in NET Framework/WPF, .NETCore/WPF. I  no nothing bout UWP. Mabye the API is slightly different here.

Comment: My problem is not to change the bindings themselves but to access them since they're in a DataTemplate. I can't just modify directly the XAML object directly.

Comment: Once you've loaded "the UI" you can as well access the uielements that have been generated through a template (and also their bindings). But as far as I know you can't hack into a DataTemplate prior to loading it. At least not with reasonable effort.

Comment: Another way to go would be to analyze the (data) type of each property and to serve an appropiate template based on the data type.
For a listview you could utilize the `CellTemplateSelector` property of a `GridViewColumn` to tailor the data template appropriaterly. Maybe you'll need a wrapper for the bound data, that serves as an adapter for the name to bind, which you don't know in advance.

Comment: @lidqy can't you show an example on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I've finally found a solution to this problem.

I was creating the DataTemplate in the XAML but I realized that with the `XAMLReader` I can do this by parsing the code from the code behind.

I've created a function called `GenerateDataTemplate()` and there I use an instance of `StringBuilder` to build the XAML code and when returning I use the function `ToString()` so I can get the full XAML code in one string maintaining some ease on reading it. After that, I've just used `XamlReader.Load(GenerateDataTemplate())` and casted it to a `DataTemplate` and applied it to my `ListView.ItemTemplate`.

My Code:

```
   protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var param = (Dictionary<string, object>)e.Parameter;
        _ItemsList = (List<object>)param["itemsList"];
        _Fields = (Dictionary<string, string>)param["fields"];

        _DetailsPage = (Type)param["detailPage"];
        ObjListView.ItemsSource = UniversalAutoSuggestBox.ItemsSource = _ItemsList;

        ObjListView.ItemTemplate = NormalItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(GenerateDataTemplate("NormalItemTemplate"));
        SelectedItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(GenerateDataTemplate("SelectedItemTemplate"));
    }

    public string GenerateDataTemplate(string param)
    {
        StringBuilder sbTemp = new();

        //Data Template definition
        if (param == "NormalItemTemplate") sbTemp.Append("<DataTemplate x:Key=\"NormalItemTemplate\" ");
        if (param == "SelectedItemTemplate") sbTemp.Append("<DataTemplate x:Key=\"SelectedItemTemplate\" ");
        sbTemp.Append(@"xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"" ");
        sbTemp.Append(@"xmlns:x=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"">");

        //Grid definition
        sbTemp.Append("<Grid MinWidth=\"350\" Margin=\"5\">");

        //Grid row definition
        sbTemp.Append("<Grid.RowDefinitions>");
        sbTemp.Append("<RowDefinition Height = \"*\" />");
        sbTemp.Append("<RowDefinition Height = \"*\" />");
        sbTemp.Append("<RowDefinition Height = \"*\" />");
        sbTemp.Append("</Grid.RowDefinitions>");

        //Grid column definition
        sbTemp.Append("<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>");
        sbTemp.Append("<ColumnDefinition Width = \"Auto\"/>");
        sbTemp.Append("<ColumnDefinition Width = \"*\" />");
        sbTemp.Append("</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>");

        //Ellipse definition 
        sbTemp.Append("<Ellipse Grid.Row=\"0\" Grid.RowSpan=\"2\" Width = \"32\" Height = \"32\" Margin = \"6\" VerticalAlignment = \"Center\" HorizontalAlignment = \"Center\">");
        sbTemp.Append("<Ellipse.Fill> <ImageBrush x:Name =\"LogoImage\" ImageSource = \"{Binding " + _Fields["Image"] + "}\" /> </Ellipse.Fill > ");
        sbTemp.Append("</Ellipse>");

        //Header Text Block Definition
        sbTemp.Append("<TextBlock Grid.Row = \"0\" Grid.Column = \"1\" Text = \"{Binding " + _Fields["Header"] + "}\" Style = \"{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}\" Margin = \"12,6,0,0\"/> ");

        //Subheader Text Block Definition 
        sbTemp.Append("<TextBlock  Grid.Row=\"1\" Grid.Column = \"1\" Text = \"{Binding " + _Fields["Subheader"] + "}\" Style = \"{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}\" Margin = \"12,0,0,6\" /> ");

        //Button (case Selected)
        if(param == "SelectedItemTemplate")
        {
            sbTemp.Append("<StackPanel Grid.Row=\"2\" Grid.Column=\"1\" Orientation =\"Horizontal\" HorizontalAlignment =\"Right\" Spacing = \"5\" > ");
            sbTemp.Append("<Button Content=\"Editar\" Click=\"AlterButton_Click\"/>");
            sbTemp.Append("</StackPanel>");
        }
            
        //Grid end
        sbTemp.Append("</Grid>");
        //DataTemplate end
        sbTemp.Append("</DataTemplate>");

        return sbTemp.ToString();
    }
```

With this approach, I can't just do what I were needing from my question but also with some more code lines create a second `DataTemplate` for when an item from the `ListView` is selected.

Now I just need to figure out how to get the button working :).

**IMPORTANT**

Don't forget to append the following lines:

```
sbTemp.Append(@"xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"" ");

    sbTemp.Append(@"xmlns:x=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"">");
```

If you don't append these the `XAMLReader` will throw a `XAML Parse Error`.

Sources:
https://www.programmersought.com/article/7917516170/

https://living-sun.com/pt/xaml/866432-passing-resource-to-xamlreader-xaml-uwp.html (In Portuguese)

**Hope this can save hours for someone else. :)**